# samsung laptop Battery Issue wont fully charge

Tags: laptop, battery

I have a samsung laptop and recently had a pop up message saying for `battery to not completely charge to save battery life` after doing this my battery does not completely charge. It charges to approx 50% but this does not allow me to use my computer for very long which is very frustrating, Anyone know how I can change the setting of my battery to go back to fully charge as I cannot seem to find anything in my battery options that allows me to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Charging battery in fully cause battery life reduced, for this reason all laptops have software which lets you to determine how much battery charged.

In my VAIO laptop I change it to 80% like below picture:

[image]

**And you must have this option in Samsung software on your laptop.**
I guess this options in samsung is in:

Start > All programs > Samsung > Battery Life Extender > Battery Life Extender

Answer (score 1):

The system has `Battery Life Extender` installed in it. By disabling that you can charge to 100%. For doing that goto

```
Start > All Programs > Samsung > Battery Life Extender > Battery Life Extender
```

You will see a screen similar to this:

[image: 1]

In that just switch to `Normal Battery Mode`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your laptop is some years old, and reduced battery health is a normal behaviour (especially if your laptop was often connected to power supply even if not necessary).

Comment: Please read again he said: **after doing this** my batter does not completely charge it charges to approx 50%

Comment: after popup his battery charged to approx 50%, this is how I understood that sentence.

Maybe system is charging battery up to 50% only, because it noticed battery was going down rapidly (health was below, for example, 70%).

Answer (score 0):

Hope your operating system is windows and system life extender is on in your laptop.make the option to normal by going to 
`Start --> All Programs --> Samsung --> Battery Life Extender --> Battery Life Extender`
Check whether your laptop charges fully after doing this. if not try different power options available in windows operating system, click restore to default in power options before trying it.If all these things are not working, then try to swap your battery and check.